# dynamic export variable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to export a variable in node js that initialize after click on button?

File from which i export:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let settings = req.body;
  module.exports.settings = settings;
  res.send('/testroom');
});
```

File from which i import

```
let { settings } = require('./pretest');
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('settings', settings);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/html/testroom.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost got it right, but when you get the value on the other route it will be already declared and initialized with the first value of the `setting`

```js
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let settings = req.body;
  exports.settings = settings;
  res.send('/testroom');
});


router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // here its scoped with route when its called its gets the current value
    let { settings } = require('./pretest');
    console.log('settings', settings);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/html/testroom.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it started working, when i changed "exports.settings" to "module.exports.settings"